# Placing some razor pages in a different assembly - blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor

Like to have some of the razor pages as blazor components in a different assembly,
What is the procedure and best-practice to do this?

**BlazorComponents** --> Type of Razor Class Library, I placed counter.razor here

**BlazorServerApp**

In the Imports I imported the `@using BlazorComponents` namespace, 
but when running seems still doesn't have access to counter page via `/counter`

Using all the latest versions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taken from the Microsoft docs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Use the AdditionalAssemblies parameter to specify additional assemblies for the Router component to consider when searching for routable components. Specified assemblies are considered in addition to the AppAssembly-specified assembly. In the following example, Component1 is a routable component defined in a referenced class library. The following AdditionalAssemblies example results in routing support for Component1:

```
<Router
    AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly"
    AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Component1).Assembly }">
...
</Router>
```

Comment: A quick note that this is Blazor, so everything is components. You can write some code the searches for additional assemblies, e.g. that implement an interface, then set the value for `AdditionalAssemblies` in code.. coool

Comment: Yes @Quango, quite know that, earlier in MVC I wrote a "View Engine" and turned all my pages in partial views,as well as other types of viewcomponents for everything, trying to achieve CBD (component-Based-Development", currently also like to know such way which gives me more power and customization, would be glad if you know a proven way which you can provide to me. What interface? and how to achieve the idea? (the usage)